# How to read a Microsoft Excel file into a Buffer using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, excel

I am reading an Excel file into a Javascript Buffer but it is corrupted after uploading the file to AWS S3. Here is the code snippet that reads the file:

```js
        import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
        import  path  from 'path';  
      
        const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
        const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

        export const readFileAsStream1 = (file:string): Buffer => {
           
            const fileAsString = readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, file),'utf-8')
                                        
            return Buffer.from(fileAsString)
        }
```

Unfortunately, this does not produce an Excel compatible file when uploaded to S3. The resulting buffer is not right. What I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a utility function which worked. I read the file using fs.createReadStream instead and used my utility function

```js
    export const readFileAsStream = async(file): Promise<Buffer> => {
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(path.resolve(__dirname, file))
    const buffer = await streamTobuffer(stream);
    return buffer;
  }
```